SecPKCS12Import failed on iOS 17.5, but work well on iOS 18.0
I have been using SecPKCS12Import to retrieve the kSecImportItemIdentity from a .p12 certificate.
While this method works well on iOS 18.0, it returns an error code -25293 on iOS 17.5 or lower.
I use Swift ver 5.0 and XCode 16, the password contains a mix of lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers, and special characters ( ! and * ) for enhanced security.
let certURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: “my_certificate”, withExtension: "p12")
 
 guard let certURL = certURL,
        let pkcs12Data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: certURL.path)) else {
          print ("Failed to load .p12 file.")
          throw NSError(…)
      }

      let cfPkcs12Data = pkcs12Data as CFData

      let options: [String: Any] = [
          kSecImportExportPassphrase as String: “my_password”
      ]
      var results: CFArray?

      let status = SecPKCS12Import(cfPkcs12Data, options as NSDictionary, &results)`

Has anyone encountered this issue before, and what might be causing it? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!
I have running this on orther iOS version but it only work on iOS 18.0 or higher

After research, it seems like a problem with Open SSL version 3 and iOS. I found this one: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/723242
